# Bingo Game that needs someone to look over because of repetitive coding

Tags: java, beginner, array, game

I am a beginner Java programmer and am in need of someone to read over it and help me condense my repetitive coding. I wrote code for a Bingo game and feel like I repeat code too often. If anyone could help me with my over obsessive use of repetitive code it would be greatly appreciated

```
package bingo;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

public class Bingo {

    static int b[] = new int[5];
    static int i[] = new int[5];
    static int n[] = new int[4];
    static int g[] = new int[5];
    static int o[] = new int[5];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        start();
    }

    public static void start() {
        //Creating Variables for the frame...
        JFrame k = new JFrame("Bingo!");
        JLabel bk = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/bk.png"));
        JButton Play = new JButton();
        JButton view = new JButton();
        JLabel nice = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/bk2.png"));

        //Setting size of JFrame...
        k.setSize(600, 680);
        k.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Setting the location of the labels
        bk.setBounds(-10, 170, 600, 200);
        Play.setBounds(190, 400, 190, 100);
        nice.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 680);
        view.setBounds(235, 520, 100, 50);

        Play.setForeground(Color.BLACK);//sets foreground/background/font
        Play.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        Play.setFocusPainted(false);
        Play.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 12));
        Play.setText("Generate Card");

        view.setForeground(Color.WHITE);//sets foreground/background/font
        view.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        view.setFocusPainted(false);
        view.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 10));
        view.setText("Cards");

        k.add(bk);
        k.add(Play);
        k.add(view);
        k.add(nice);
        k.setLayout(null);
        k.setVisible(true);

        Play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Action Listener when called, calls random();
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                k.dispose();
                random();
            }

        });
        view.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Action Listener when pressing "Generate Card"
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                k.dispose();
                stats();
            }

        }); //Action listener when called, calls stats();
    }

    public static void stats() {
        JFrame k = new JFrame();//creating variables for all labels
        JLabel bk = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/bk2.png"));
        JLabel title = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/title.png"));
        JLabel star = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/star.png"));
        JButton gen = new JButton();
        JButton back = new JButton("Back");
        back.setForeground(Color.WHITE);//sets foreground/background/font
        back.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        back.setFocusPainted(false);

        gen.setText("Generate Card");//sets foreground/background/font
        gen.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        gen.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        gen.setFocusPainted(false);
        int x = 175;

        JTextField B[] = new JTextField[5];//Jtextfield arrays for user input
        JTextField I[] = new JTextField[5];
        JTextField N[] = new JTextField[4];
        JTextField G[] = new JTextField[5];
        JTextField O[] = new JTextField[5];

        for (int p = 0; p < B.length; p++) {//for loops that set bounds to each index in each Jtextfield array
            B[p] = new JTextField();
            B[p].setBounds(100, x, 75, 75);
            x = x + 75;
            B[p].setOpaque(false);
            k.add(B[p]);

        }
        x = 175;
        for (int p = 0; p < I.length; p++) {
            I[p] = new JTextField();
            I[p].setBounds(175, x, 75, 75);
            x = x + 75;
            I[p].setOpaque(false);
            k.add(I[p]);
        }
        x = 175;
        for (int p = 0; p < N.length; p++) {
            N[p] = new JTextField();
            while (x == 325) {
                x = x + 75;
            }
            N[p].setBounds(250, x, 75, 75);
            x = x + 75;
            N[p].setOpaque(false);
            k.add(N[p]);
        }
        x = 175;
        for (int p = 0; p < G.length; p++) {
            G[p] = new JTextField();
            G[p].setBounds(325, x, 75, 75);
            x = x + 75;
            G[p].setOpaque(false);
            k.add(G[p]);
        }
        x = 175;
        for (int p = 0; p < O.length; p++) {
            O[p] = new JTextField();
            O[p].setBounds(400, x, 75, 75);
            x = x + 75;
            O[p].setOpaque(false);
            k.add(O[p]);
        }

        for (int p = 0; p < B.length; p++) {
            try {
                N[p].setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 18));
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            B[p].setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 18));//sets font of the text field
            I[p].setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 18));
            G[p].setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 18));
            O[p].setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 18));

        }

        B[0].setText("1-15");// sets range in text field that user is instructed to input
        I[0].setText("16-30");
        N[0].setText("31-45");
        G[0].setText("46-60");
        O[0].setText("61-75");

        back.setBounds(400, 570, 75, 40);
        title.setBounds(40, 60, 500, 114);
        gen.setBounds(190, 570, 190, 50);// sets bounds of all labels/button
        bk.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 680);
        star.setBounds(250, 325, 75, 75);
        k.setSize(600, 680);
        k.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        k.add(back);
        k.add(star);
        k.add(title);
        k.add(gen);
        k.add(bk);
        k.setLayout(null);
        k.setVisible(true);

        gen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Action Listener when called, check
            String BS[] = new String[5];
            String IS[] = new String[5];
            String NS[] = new String[4];
            String GS[] = new String[5];
            String OS[] = new String[5];
            int Bi[] = new int[5];
            int Ii[] = new int[5];
            int Ni[] = new int[4];
            int Gi[] = new int[5];
            int Oi[] = new int[5];

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                boolean isGood = true;
                try {
                    for (int p = 0; p < B.length; p++) {
                        try {
                            BS[p] = B[p].getText();
                            Bi[p] = Integer.parseInt(BS[p]);
                            IS[p] = I[p].getText();
                            Ii[p] = Integer.parseInt(IS[p]);
                            NS[p] = N[p].getText();
                            Ni[p] = Integer.parseInt(NS[p]);
                            GS[p] = G[p].getText();
                            Gi[p] = Integer.parseInt(GS[p]);
                            OS[p] = O[p].getText();
                            Oi[p] = Integer.parseInt(OS[p]);
                        } catch (Exception ign) {
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    isGood = false;
                }

                if (isGood == false) {
                    card(Bi, Ii, Ni, Gi, Oi);
                    k.dispose();
                } else{
                    B[0].setText("Invalid!");
                    I[0].setText("Enter");
                    N[0].setText("Numbers");
                    G[0].setText("To");
                    O[0].setText("Continue");
                }

            }
        });
        back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Action Listener when pressing "Generate Card"
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                k.dispose();
                start();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void random() { // Random number Generator method, is called when action listener runs
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int p = 0; p < b.length; p++) { //The loops are to check for duplication in random numbers
            b[p] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 1);
            do {
                b[1] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 1);
            } while (b[1] == b[0]);
            do {
                b[2] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 1);
            } while (b[2] == b[1] || b[2] == b[0]);
            do {
                b[3] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 1);
            } while (b[3] == b[0] || b[3] == b[1] || b[3] == b[2]);
            do {
                b[4] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 1);
            } while (b[4] == b[0] || b[4] == b[1] || b[4] == b[2] || b[4] == b[3]);

        }

        for (int p = 0; p < i.length; p++) {  //The loops are to check for duplication in random numbers
            i[p] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 16);
            do {
                i[1] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 16);
            } while (i[1] == i[0]);
            do {
                i[2] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 16);
            } while (i[2] == i[1] || i[2] == i[0]);
            do {
                i[3] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 16);
            } while (i[3] == i[0] || i[3] == i[1] || i[3] == i[2]);
            do {
                i[4] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 16);
            } while (i[4] == i[0] || i[4] == i[1] || i[4] == i[2] || i[4] == i[3]);

        }

        for (int p = 0; p < n.length; p++) {  //The loops are to check for duplication in random numbers
            n[p] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 31);
            do {
                n[1] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 31);
            } while (n[1] == n[0]);
            do {
                n[2] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 31);
            } while (n[2] == n[1] || n[2] == n[0]);
            do {
                n[3] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 31);
            } while (n[3] == n[0] || n[3] == n[1] || n[3] == n[2]);

        }
        for (int p = 0; p < n.length; p++) {  //The loops are to check for duplication in random numbers
            g[p] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 46);
            do {
                g[1] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 46);
            } while (g[1] == g[0]);
            do {
                g[2] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 46);
            } while (g[2] == g[1] || g[2] == g[0]);
            do {
                g[3] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 46);
            } while (g[3] == g[0] || g[3] == g[1] || g[3] == g[2]);
            do {
                g[4] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 46);
            } while (g[4] == g[0] || g[4] == g[1] || g[4] == g[2] || g[4] == g[3]);

        }
        for (int p = 0; p < n.length; p++) {  //The loops are to check for duplication in random numbers
            o[p] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 61);
            do {
                o[1] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 61);
            } while (o[1] == o[0]);
            do {
                o[2] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 61);
            } while (o[2] == o[1] || o[2] == o[0]);
            do {
                o[3] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 61);
            } while (o[3] == o[0] || o[3] == o[1] || o[3] == o[2]);
            do {
                o[4] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * 14 + 61);
            } while (o[4] == o[0] || o[4] == o[1] || o[4] == o[2] || o[4] == o[3]);

        }
        card(b, i, n, g, o);

    }

    public static void card(int[] b, int[] i, int[] n, int[] g, int[] o) { //Creates frame for card
        JFrame R = new JFrame("Bingo!");
        int x = 175;
        JButton reset = new JButton();
        reset.setText("Generate New  Card");
        reset.setBounds(195, 570, 190, 40);
        reset.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        reset.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        reset.setFocusPainted(false);

        R.setSize(600, 680);
        R.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel title = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/title.png"));
        JLabel star = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/star.png"));
        JLabel nice = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/bk2.png"));
        JButton back = new JButton("Back");
        back.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        back.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        back.setFocusPainted(false);

        back.setBounds(400, 570, 75, 40);
        title.setBounds(40, 60, 500, 114);
        star.setBounds(250, 325, 75, 75);
        nice.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 680);

        //Creating JButtons for Bingo card
        JButton B[] = new JButton[5];
        String b1[] = new String[5];
        JButton I[] = new JButton[5];
        String i1[] = new String[5];
        JButton N[] = new JButton[4];
        String n1[] = new String[4];
        JButton G[] = new JButton[5];
        String g1[] = new String[5];
        JButton O[] = new JButton[5];
        String o1[] = new String[5];

        //For loops to setText to all of the buttons
        for (int p = 0; p < b.length; p++) {
            b1[p] = String.valueOf(b[p]);
            B[p] = new JButton();
            B[p].setText(b1[p]);
            B[p].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            B[p].setContentAreaFilled(false);
            B[p].setFocusPainted(false);
            B[p].setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 26));
            R.add(B[p]);
        }
        for (int p = 0; p < i.length; p++) {
            i1[p] = String.valueOf(i[p]);
            I[p] = new JButton();
            I[p].setText(i1[p]);
            I[p].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            I[p].setContentAreaFilled(false);
            I[p].setFocusPainted(false);
            I[p].setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 26));
            R.add(I[p]);
        }
        for (int p = 0; p < n.length; p++) {
            n1[p] = String.valueOf(n[p]);
            N[p] = new JButton();
            N[p].setText(n1[p]);
            N[p].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            N[p].setContentAreaFilled(false);
            N[p].setFocusPainted(false);
            N[p].setFont(new Font("Comnc Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 26));
            R.add(N[p]);
        }
        for (int p = 0; p < g.length; p++) {
            g1[p] = String.valueOf(g[p]);
            G[p] = new JButton();
            G[p].setText(g1[p]);
            G[p].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            G[p].setContentAreaFilled(false);
            G[p].setFocusPainted(false);
            G[p].setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 26));
            R.add(G[p]);
        }
        for (int p = 0; p < o.length; p++) {
            o1[p] = String.valueOf(o[p]);
            O[p] = new JButton();
            O[p].setText(o1[p]);
            O[p].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            O[p].setContentAreaFilled(false);
            O[p].setFocusPainted(false);
            O[p].setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 26));
            R.add(O[p]);
        }

        for (int p = 0; p < b.length; p++) {
            B[p].setBounds(100, x, 75, 75);
            x = x + 75;
        }
        x = 175;
        for (int p = 0; p < I.length; p++) {
            I[p].setBounds(175, x, 75, 75);
            x = x + 75;
        }
        x = 175;
        for (int p = 0; p < N.length; p++) {
            while (x == 325) {
                x = x + 75;
            }
            N[p].setBounds(250, x, 75, 75);

            x = x + 75;
        }
        x = 175;
        for (int p = 0; p < G.length; p++) {
            G[p].setBounds(325, x, 75, 75);
            x = x + 75;
        }
        x = 175;
        for (int p = 0; p < O.length; p++) {
            O[p].setBounds(400, x, 75, 75);
            x = x + 75;
        }

        R.add(title);//adds all of the components to the Frame...
        R.add(back);
        R.add(reset);
        R.add(star);
        R.add(nice);
        R.setLayout(null);
        R.setVisible(true);

        reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Action Listener when pressing "Generate Card"
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                R.dispose();
                random();

            }

        });
        back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Action Listener when pressing "Generate Card"
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                R.dispose();
                start();

            }

        });
        B[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    B[0].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    B[0].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        B[1].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    B[1].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    B[1].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        B[2].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    B[2].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    B[2].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        B[3].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    B[3].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    B[3].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        B[4].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    B[4].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    B[4].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        I[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    I[0].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    I[0].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        I[1].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    I[1].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    I[1].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        I[2].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    I[2].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    I[2].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        I[3].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    I[3].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    I[3].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        I[4].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    I[4].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    I[4].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        N[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    N[0].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    N[0].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        N[1].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    N[1].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    N[1].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        N[2].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    N[2].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    N[2].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        N[3].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    N[3].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    N[3].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        G[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    G[0].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    G[0].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        G[1].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    G[1].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    G[1].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        G[2].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    G[2].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    G[2].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        G[3].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    G[3].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    G[3].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        G[4].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    G[4].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    G[4].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        O[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    O[0].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    O[0].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        O[1].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    O[1].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    O[1].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        O[2].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    O[2].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    O[2].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        O[3].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    O[3].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    O[3].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });
        O[4].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private boolean right = false;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    O[4].setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (right) {
                    O[4].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're thinking too procedural instead of actually using Java in the way it's designed to be used. This is most obvious in that you're only ever using static methods that don't even return anything.

Correcting everything would be a bit out of scope of this review so I'll give some pointers on how to improve your current code without changing *too* much. In no particular order, here's my list of changes I suggest, in order that I encountered them:

## variable naming conventions

The java convention is to start variable names with a small case  That way it's immediatly clear when something is a variable name and when it's a class name.
`JButton Play` should be `play` instead.

Variables should also get meaningful names. Editors these days usually include autocomplete anyway so it doesn't take much more typing to use longer names. Other people using (or reviewing) your code will be thankful if you don't use one letter variables.
Variables like `b`, `i`, ... could be namend `columnB` ... instead, `k` should probably be something like `frame` and `bk` took me way longer than I'd like to admit before I figured out that it's the `background` for the application.

The only exceptions where one letter variables are commonly used is in a for loop. The convention is to use `i` (or `j` in a nested loop) instead of how you used `p`.

## static fields

These made me think you don't understand OOP yet. Since they're used only inside the `random()` method, the easiest quickfix for now is to just move them inside that method.

Static fields are rarely useful, except if they're constants, in which case they should also be declared `final` (and following Java naming conventions written in ALLCAPS). At some point you'll want to introduce an actual instance of one of your classes and use non-static fields. I'm considering that out of scope of this review for now. It's advisable you search for a Java tutorial to explain how to use classes and objects.

## random.double()

I don't like casting if you don't need it.
This should probably be replaced with `random.nextInt(to - from + 1) + from`.

## removing random generation repetition.

One of the most obvious points where repetition can be avoided is in your `random()` method. My initial thought was to provide a new helper method like this:

```
private static int[] generateRandomNumbers(int from, int to) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] result = new int[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        boolean found = false;
        while(!found) {
            result[i] = random.nextInt(to-from+1)+from;
            found = true;
            for(int j = 0; j<i; j++){
                if(result[i] == result[j]) {
                    found = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Which can be used for all the columns except for the middle one. The only difference is the size of the array to be returned. So if we pass that in as a variable as well we can simplify your entire `random()` method to this:

```
public static void random() { // Random number Generator method, is called when action listener runs
    int b[] = generateRandomNumbers(1, 15, 5);
    int i[] = generateRandomNumbers(16, 30, 5);
    int n[] = generateRandomNumbers(31, 45, 4);
    int g[] = generateRandomNumbers(46, 60, 5);
    int o[] = generateRandomNumbers(61, 75, 5);

    card(b, i, n, g, o);
}

private static int[] generateRandomNumbers(int from, int to, int amount) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] result = new int[amount];
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        boolean found = false;
        while (!found) {
            result[i] = random.nextInt(to - from + 1) + from;
            found = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (result[i] == result[j]) {
                    found = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

## removing button creation repetition

Another place where you repeat the same lines over and over is when you're creating all the buttons inside the `card` method.

Let's start by creating a helper method that creates a button

```
private static JButton createButton( String text) {
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setText(text);
    button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button.setFocusPainted(false);
    button.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 26));
    return button;
}
```

That way we can simplify the for loops to create the buttons to:

```
    //For loops to setText to all of the buttons
    for (int p = 0; p < b.length; p++) {
        b1[p] = String.valueOf(b[p]);
        columnB[p] = createButton(b1[p]);
        frame.add(columnB[p]);
    }
```

I also noticed that the `b1` array is only used inside that loop, so we can inline that instead to remove that variable altogether:

```
    //For loops to setText to all of the buttons
    for (int p = 0; p < b.length; p++) {
        columnB[p] = createButton(String.valueOf(b[p]));
        frame.add(columnB[p]);
    }
```

A bit further into the method there's a lot of repetition to add a click listener to each of the buttons. We can just add that listener inside our new helper method so that it's already done for each of the buttons when they're created. That way we can remove all of that repetition.

```
private static JButton createButton( String text) {
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setText(text);
    button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button.setFocusPainted(false);
    button.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 26));
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        private boolean right = false;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!right) {
                button.setForeground(Color.red);
            } else if (right) {
                button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }
            right = !right;
        }
    });
    return button;
}
```

## layout manager

You should really consider using a layout manager instead of hard coding positions yourself. Explaining how to use one is a bit too much to do in this review. I suggest looking up how to use a `MigLayout` for example where you can define a 5x5 grid. That way it's enough to just add the buttons in the earlier mentioned for loops without explicitly setting each of the bounds.

## handling middle square

An idea that could further simplify your code is to first not treat the middle square as anything special and actually create a 5x5 grid instead of separate columns. Then only where it actually matters make the difference for that middle square. That way you can do things like:

```
public static void card(int[][] numberGrid) {
....    

for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col ++) {
        if (row == 2 && col == 2) {
            R.add(new JLabel("Free square!"));  //todo replace with something useful                  
        } else {
            R.add(createButton(String.valueOf(numberGrid[row][col])));
        }
    }
}
```

I'll leave figuring out how to update the rest of your code to use such a grid up to you.

## one frame

It's probably nicer if you can only create one frame for your application and keep using that one instead of always disposing your frame and creating a new one. This may require actually using an instance of your Bingo class to store the frame in so I'll leave it out of scope of this review.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and reviewing my code, it really means a lot to someone like me that is new to the program and community!